# Как сделать эффект "Туман Войны" используя графические примитивы?

Tags: java, opengl

Делаю игру (курсовой проект) и надо создать эффект "Туман Войны" (это когда первоначально карта вся затемнена и открывается постепенно вокруг персонажа при его движении). 
Использую `Slick` (игровая библиотека основанная на `LWJGL`). Видел на форуме этой библиотеки создание такого эффекта, но там очень сложно (мне уж по крайней мере). 
Появилась идея как сделать это самому используя круг и прямоугольник. Рисуем карту, рисуем персонажа, поверх всего рисуем черный прямоугольник с прозрачным "как бы встроеным" кругом . При движении персонажа, к этой фигуре (круг+прямоугольник) будет добавляться новый прозрачный круг с другими координатами. 
Незнаю как соединить прямоугольник и круг так, как мне надо. 
Круг заливаю прозрачным цветом, там есть класс     `Color (red, green, blue, alpha)`

P.S работа с прямоугольником и кругом практически такая же, как и в `AWT`.

P.P.S возможно моя идея бредовая и не эффективная, если знаете реализацию "тумана войны" лучше и проще скажите мне её пожалуйста)

`LWJGL` - работа с `openGL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно и без примитивов обойтись. По идее, в OpenGL была такая фича как координаты тумана, позволяющая задать уровень затуманенности отдельных частей сцены. Координаты тумана - это атрибут вершины, а туман - тот, который настраивается через glFog.

Можно сделать сетку(допустим, M*N, где M,N - размеры карты) из квадов чёрного цвета и по мере продвижения игрока выставлять её вершинам ненулевую альфу. Сетку рисовать поверх левела, конечно же.

Можно взять текстуру(изначально - чёрную/непрозрачную), при каждом передвижении игрока отрисовать в неё прозрачную область(рендеринг в текстуру может быть непривычным, но эта техника весьма распространена и даёт отличные результаты, в том числе и в этом случае), а потом натянуть эту текстуру на один квад размером на всю карту и отрисовать поверх всего.

Если какие-то техники заинтересовали - могу рассказать подробнее :)

Comment: спасибо за столько идей)) 

Я наверное с сеткой попробую) это надо создать M*N квадратов?) не будет ли это лагать?)

Comment: ++glFog; // для курсовой покатит

Comment: да, если сетка, это нужно MxN квадратов. Если их держать в массиве и изменять только некоторые вершины по мере необходимости (если точнее, изменять только цвет вершин), и их не слишком много (порядка 100x100, или как-то так) - видеокарта легко потянет.
Всё-таки я рекомендовал бы один квадрат с текстурой, задающей прозрачность, но эта техника посложнее.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал так, на примере [tilemap](http://www.mapeditor.org/) делаем карту, спрайты тумана войны и накладываем  их поверх   карты,
то есть первоначально вся карта будет под спрайтами тумана, на карте делаем точку(respawn),
где появляется персонаж в начале игры и задаём параметры, чтобы вокруг него, в радиусе нескольких
тайлов, спрайты тумана исчезали, вот так вот.

Comment: поддерживаю. Хотел предложить аналогичный вариант.

Comment: а если без спрайтов?) 
спасибо за ответ)

Comment: ну без спрайтов openGL, наверное)